# How to delete all line not containing a pattern or another pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I know I must use the command :v, but I don't find on internet the right key to match 2 patterns.

I'd like to run this kind of command:

```
:v/OneWord .or. AnotherWord/d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine them with `\|`, which stands for *alternating branches*:

```
:v/OneWord\|AnotherWord/d
```

Since that was so simple, here are two recipies for the opposite, matching lines where *both* words match:

```
:v/.*OneWord\&.*AnotherWord/d
:v/\%(OneWord.*AnotherWord\)\|\%(AnotherWord.*OneWord\)/d
```